# root of periodic continued fraction

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, continued-fractions

Let $\xi \in \mathbb{R}$ be a periodic continued fraction expansion with  $\xi =[\overline{c_0,\dots,c_n}], c_0  \neq0 $ and $\frac{
k_i}{l_i}$ the approximate fraction with $1 \leqslant i \leqslant n$. Show $\frac{-1}{\xi'}$ with $\xi'=[\overline{c_n,\dots,c_0}]$ is polynomial root of $f(x)=l_nx^2+(l_{n-1}-k_n)x-k_{n-1}$. Use: $[{c_n,\dots,c_0}]= \frac{k_n}{k_{n-1}}$ and $[{c_n,\dots,c_1}]= \frac{l_n}{l_{n-1}}$.

Comment: A purely periodic continued fraction (integer coefficients) gives a root of a "reduced" quadratic $a x^2 + b x + c,$ where reduced means integers, also $ac < 0$ and $b > |a+c|$

Comment: This looks like a carefully copied exercise without any clear evidence that you digested the problem.  You might assuage Readers concerns by giving some context about your interest in the problem or the difficulty you see in tackling it.

Comment: Actually I need a hint because I really don't know how to start solving the  exercise.